# Are AirTags safe for pets?

Tags: dogs

While our dog is microchipped, my family is considering an extra layer of protection by using an AirTag on our dog's collar in case of an unforeseen escape.

Are there any safety considerations to keep in mind before deciding to use an AirTag on our dog's collar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AirTags contain batteries. There are [numerous reports](https://www.yahoo.com/lifestyle/why-shouldn-t-airtag-track-205536057.html?guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAAABFs8C5wEuqNTf3JJKx16OcVoN_p0NFGLtXFLuBMusabefpNiwGUjqODIbQvOK8tBM2OuiNrXAWBArUcQoFF6bp1Erdt49ZRg-dh9CFAkPjkLxendkjlLk_UF1bBYmDmitwqvQ1U2_PO6GJH7U6zlAREAyo2sKxJoVV6eKOGslz) of dogs swallowing them. Generally, it should pass through them, but if the tag is damaged before swallowing, the acid in the battery could be a concern.

Additional consideration should be given if your dog does a lot of playing with other dogs. Rabies tags and other tags typically worn on the collar are generally all metal and not likely to be torn or chewed apart, whereas many AirTag collar holders are very susceptible to damage. Many dogs (including mine) will bite at the neck or collar during play and this could be a concern. If you do get one, ensure it is more securely attached to the collar and not dangling.

Answer (score 1):

Its an *extremely* common thing here with rescued street dogs here in singapore, and generally it is *very* useful should a dog run away - providing longer term, very good high quality tracking.

I'd say, considering the size, its about as 'safe'/'dangerous' as any other tag. If your dog is the sort to chew on things like that and swallow it its a bad idea. If you feel your dog is a flight risk, its probably a very good idea.

I've not heard of any cases of it being dangerous, but there's a good many success stories for its use

Answer (score 0):

Should be roughly as safe as anything the same size and shape attached to the collar. Certainly no worse than the cell phones we carry continuously.